# Spring oauth 2 {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad credentials"}

Tags: spring, oauth

Here is my spring config:

I have created a new user in MySQL table. It always works with the user `client1`
but when a new user added, the above error (as in title) would be throw:

> Spring oauth 2 {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Bad
>   credentials"}

In addition, I get 
error while creating bean:

> 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager':  Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type
>   [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]:
>   Ambiguous constructor argument types
>    - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

From the Spring trace log, I get:

> spring-security-oauth2
>   2.0.6.RELEASE

I am using JDBC store MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question is not very readable, and it does not contain any spring configuration either. You may want to edit your question using source code formatting and update it with the missing information. This will help others and greatly increase the probability of a helpful answer. Read more on how to ask in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: But the editor says its too long. What are the restrictions? could you please help.

Comment: I use the following spring oauth2 jar. <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <bean id="clientDetails"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
  <constructor-arg index="0">
   <ref bean="dataSource" />
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>

Comment: <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
  <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>

Comment: <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <sec:authentication-provider
   user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
 </sec:authentication-manager>

Comment: <bean id="tokenStore"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="authorizationCodeServices"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>

Comment: <bean id="tokenServices"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
  <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
  <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
  <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>

 <!-- A user approval handler that remembers approval decisions by consulting 
  existing tokens -->
 <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
  <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>

Comment: <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
  <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
  <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
 </bean>

Comment: <oauth:authorization-server
  client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
  user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
  <oauth:authorization-code
   authorization-code-services-ref="authorizationCodeServices" />
  <oauth:implicit />
  <oauth:refresh-token />
  <oauth:client-credentials />
  <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" />
 </oauth:authorization-server>

Comment: <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
  resource-id="bsverealm" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

 <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
  class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="realmName" value="bsverealm" />
 </bean>

Comment: STOP :) Please don't use comments for this. You can delete them using the *x* besides them and then put that info into your question using the _edit_ button.

Comment: If the editor won't allow your code snippet because it is too long, you can host it on a service like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and include the link in your question.

Comment: 2015-03-08 01:08:02,467 TRACE [localhost-startStop-1] [DefaultListableBeanFactory] 
Ignoring constructor [public org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
(java.util.List,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager)] of bean 
'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument
 with index 1 of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: 
Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?